Supabase trigger restricts row insert
I've got a supabase table called my_flight_wines that has a column called wine_count.
I'm using flutterflow for the frontend.
The table is used as a temporary holding area for wines selected or input from my app and is used to display those wines in an app view of a flight.
Without the trigger in place, or when I have the trigger set to disabled, the app is able to insert and delete rows from the my_flight_wines table.
As soon as the trigger is enabled, the insert action stops inserting.
Here is my trigger function:
create function update_wine_count()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
alter table public.my_flight_wines
drop column wine_count;

alter table public.my_flight_wines
add column wine_count serial;
end;
$$;

create trigger insert_wine_count_trigger
after insert on my_flight_wines
for each statement
execute function update_wine_count();

I've written and rewritting the trigger, tried setting it up through the supabase UI.
I'm expecting the trigger to drop the existing wine_count column and create a new one after a row is added to or deleted from the table.
While I can still delete rows from my app, the trigger does not trigger the function upon row deletion.
The core query works as expected when I run it from the SQL editor.

Most likely because of the lock needed to alter the table. But why do you want to drop a column and create that same column again? If it's about the serial, or actually the sequence, just reset the sequence: SELECT setval('myseq', 0);. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html
